# Prove that there is no continuous map from $[0,1]$ onto open interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

I know the property that continuous image of compact space is compact. Here $[0,1]$ is compact and $(0,1)$ is not. Is this logic correct( / enough) or it requires something more than this? And is there any other method to prove this? Please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: See that the claim does not hold if the map is only into (0,1), and not onto.

Comment: thanks @PrinceM for this fact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct. Note that a continuous function $f$ on a compact interval $[a,b]$ attains a maximum $M$ and minumum $m$ and, by the intermediate value theorem,  $f([a,b])=[m,M]$ which is a closed interval.

Comment: Wow ! thank you so much ! this concept is more clearer to me now, because you have given it for arbitrary closed interval . :)